# Creating a type with an Int range in swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm looking at creating something like:
`typealias cell = 1...9` or `enum cell { case 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 }`
To create a more rich domain model. How can I do this in swift?

I can't do the second case because enum's require state names, but I'm interested in an elegant way of doing this.

I'd really like to be able to know that whenever I use a type of cell I would get something in that range based on compile time checking. I'd like it to work with swift 2.0 if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to have compile-time range checking on such a type. Imagine all the ways you can potentially create an integer value; most of them involve values that cannot possibly be determined until runtime.

However, this is what `assert()` is for. Use `assert()` at the beginning of any function that accepts an integer in a specific range and you'll still catch any errors nice & early!